# "Semitic" and "anti-Semitic"

Tags: meaning, terminology

Why does *Semitic* refer to several groups of people, including Babylonians, Assyrians, Arabs and Jews, whereas *anti-Semitic* only refers to Jews?

Comment: Because words mean what people use them to mean, not what some people think they ought to mean. (Not putting it in as an answer, because in a way it's not very helpful: but in a sense it is the *whole* of the answer to any question of the form "Why does/doesn't X mean Y").

Comment: @Colin: +100! excellent! where is the linguistics.SE site? But then sometimes, there -is- an explanatory reason.

Comment: @Mitch: yes indeed, the historical explanation for how a word has come to have a particular meaning is often fascinating. But it is a field rife with unverified assumptions, ingenious invention masquerading as certainty, and lots of "we just don't know".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1222233#m_en_us1222233) defines *anti-Semitism* thus:

> **anti-Semitism**
>   hostility or prejudice against Jews

And here is the relevant entry from the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=anti-semitism&searchmode=none):

> **anti-Semitism**
>   also *antisemitism*, 1881, from Ger. *Antisemitismus*, first used by Wilhelm Marr (1819–1904) German radical, nationalist and race-agitator, who founded the Antisemiten-Liga in 1879; see ***anti- + Semite***. Not etymologically restricted to anti-Jewish theories, actions, or policies, but almost always used in this sense. Those who object to the inaccuracy of the term might try H. Adler's Judaeophobia (1882). *Anti-Semitic* (also *antisemitic*) and *anti-Semite* (also *antisemite*) also are from 1881, like *anti-Semitism* they appear first in English in an article in the "Athenaeum" of Sept. 31, in reference to German literature.

*Anti-Semitic* is Jewish-specific for historical reasons, as revealed by the Etymology Dictionary. In its most literal sense, *anti-Semitic* should relate to all Semitic cultures, but this is not the case—a great example of how history, politics, etc, shape English usage.

Comment: It's like how "holocaust" could refer to any massacre (and did at one time), but nowadays almost always refers to the persecution of Jews during WWII.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I'd say only the capital-H Holocaust refers the WWII.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: It's all the same when you're speaking. (I'd also argue that, in writing, while the capital-H version formally refers to WWII, *any* mention of "holocaust", capital or not, recalls that specific one.)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Thanks for that example! I was trying to come up with one myself while composing the answer. *Apartheid* came to mind, but I wasn't too sure if it was strong enough. Haha, and I love "It's all the same when you're speaking"!!!

Comment: @Jimi  But it's not just history and politics that gave legs to the anti-Semitic = anti-Jewish fallacy. It is really down to the pseudo-intellectuals within the media of the 1800s and 1900s **allowing** the likes of Marr to get away with gross simplifications like that.

Answer (score 2):

Because when the word was coined and came into use, Jews were the only Semitic people encountered in modern European (and American) society.

Comment: Could Gypsies be considered semitic?

Comment: @oosterwal - no Romani is indo-european but not semitic.

Comment: @Colin Fine On the meta site, I commented that occasionally high-rep users were giving Answers that, while technically correct, were unsupported by any references.  I was encouraged to point this out in a comment when it occurred.  So.......