# What does the term "antisemitic" mean and how did it arrive at it's modern definition?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, terminology, rhetoric, popularity

I ask this question for two reasons. One, it's being used a lot currently in western media and online spaces such as twitter, so maybe if I could fully grasp it's definition I could understand why it's usage is so frequent right now. Two, I am of course aware of the simplistic definition giving by google but I'm confused as to how a word that (at face value) appears to refer Shemites (descendants of Noah's son Shem), actually refers to Jewish people exclusively.

Comment: See ["Etymological fallacy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy)

Comment: Wikipedia explains it all. But it originated in German, so is largely out of scope here.

Comment: Your understanding of the common meaning answers the title portion *What does the term "antisemitic" mean*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Semitic" and "anti-Semitic"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20444/semitic-and-anti-semitic)

Answer (score 0):

In Biblical mythology everybody is the descendant of one of the sons of Noah (since they are the only people to survive the Flood).

Traditionally the Jews are the descendants of Shem and the Arab peoples the descendants of Ham, and so are called Semitic and Hamitic peoples respectively.